# Assignment of function parameter has no effect outside the function

Tags: c

Why last line parameter maybe has no effect outside the function:

```
void save_last_frame( uint8_t *saveframe, uint8_t *curframe,
                             int width, int height, int savestride, int curstride )
{
    height /= 2;
    height--;
    while( height-- ) {
        blit_packed422_scanline( saveframe, curframe, width );
        saveframe += savestride;
        interpolate_packed422_scanline( saveframe, curframe, curframe + (curstride*2), width );
        saveframe += savestride;
        curframe += (curstride*2);
    }
    blit_packed422_scanline( saveframe, curframe, width );
    saveframe += savestride;
    blit_packed422_scanline( saveframe, curframe, width );
    saveframe += savestride;   // <-- Assignment of function parameter has no effect outside the function
}
```

Thanks

Comment: pointer is call by value, too. It is called on it to make a copy on the stack. It has no effect on the original if you change the copy

Comment: 0) strong advise to use *unsigned* types for indexes. 1) `height /=2; height--;` can underflow if initial height argument equals one. (note: this does *not* answer the question but can avoid a lot of collateral damage in the future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C parameters are essentially local variables which are initialized with values passed in as arguments. This means they exist only for as long as the function is being executed. Your `saveframe` variable ceases to exist once the function exists and with it the value you assigned.

In order to modify values existing outside the function you should use a pointer and modify the value **pointed to** by that pointer.

Since the value you're working with is a pointer already, you should use a pointer to pointer:

```
void save_last_frame( uint8_t **saveframe, uint8_t **curframe,
                             int width, int height, int savestride, int curstride )
```

You should then modify the code accordingly, replacing `saveframe` with `*saveframe`. Similarly for `curframe` if you also wish for it to be updated by the function.

An example of such "output pointer" argument is `endptr` used to record the end of parsed numeric string in [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol).

Answer (score 0):

You have passed the variable `saveframe` as a pointer; to change the value outside the function, do this:

```
*saveframe += savestride;
```

instead. This way, your value will now be retained even after function exits.

Comment: While this would change something outside the function, it is not clear what would be changed since `saveframe` has been incremented multiple times, so it doesn't point to what it started out pointing at.  Interestingly, there's a deleted answer (which you probably can't see because you don't have enough reputation yet) that makes exactly the same suggestion you're making here.  I can't see the comments that led to it being deleted, though.