# C actions and variables

Tags: c, function, variables, action

Why when I use:

```
char paraula[15];
int longparaula=0;
copia_paraula(paraula, longparaula);
```

It says that longparaula=0? paraula it's ok, and containd the values of the chars that I input, but longparaula always it's 0. If i don't initializate longparaula, it always equals an aleatory value. It will equals at the longitude of the array, isn't it? It's like the function can modify the valueo of "paraula", but can't modify the value of longparaula...

```
void copia_paraula(char taula[15], int Longitud){
     int i=0;
     while ((c!=' ') & (c!='.')){
           taula[i]=c;
           scanf("%c", &c);
           i++;
     }
     Longitud=i;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assignment of function parameter has no effect outside the function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133389/assignment-of-function-parameter-has-no-effect-outside-the-function)

Comment: `&` is a [bitwise operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C). Use [logical operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators)  `&&` for `and` and `||` for `or`. And if you use `taula` as a string, do not forget to add the null terminating character `'\0'` at the end.

Comment: For completeness:The `&` as used in `&c` is the "address-of" operator.

Comment: Where is `c` declared? Why use `scanf` instead of `getc`? Should test for EOF, line feed and max number of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is pass by value.

That means when `copia_paraula()` is being called `Longitud` receives a copy of what is stored in `longparaula`.

Inside `copia_paraula()` the code just modifies `Longitud`, that is the copy of `longparaula`. That's why `Longitud` does not changes its value.

To fix this pass down a "reference" to `longparaula` by passing its address, the pointer pointing to where `longparaula` is stored.

And then write the new value to where the pointer points:

```
void copia_paraula(char taula[15], int * pLongitud)
{
  int i = 0;
//  while ((c != ' ') & (c != '.')) // you do not want to perform a bit-wise "and"-operation
  while ((c != ' ') && (c != '.')) // but a logical, && is the logical "and"-operator
  {
       taula[i] = c;
       scanf("%c", &c); 
       i++;
  }

  *Longitud = i;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
char paraula[15];
int longparaula = 0;
copia_paraula(paraula, &longparaula);
```

---

Makeing sure the code does not write out of the `char`-array's bounds is left as an exercise.

Comment: Right, the right prototype for the function is `void copia_paraula(char taula[15], int* Longitud)`

Comment: I tried to fix it with your code, and now it works. If I understanded well your explanation, with the *variable, you point at the adress of the memory where the variable is stored, in this way, you can modify the value of a variable that it's declarated outside the function? I can't modify a parameter inside a function? I can't understand why I can modify "paraula" without using "*taula[15]" and can't modify "longparaula" without using "*longitud".

Comment: @JoseGutiérrez: Instead of `*Longitud = i;` one can write `Longitud[0] = i;`. Also see my updated answer. An array decays to a pointer to its 1st element when being passed to a function. When declaring a function parameter `char s[n]` is the same as `char * s`.)